# Mean stack client side update

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, mean-stack

I'm having trouble implementing the client side update CRUD logic. The fields are currently being deleted with the set up as it is. What am I missing?

My angular:

```
$scope.editService = function(id) {
        $http.put('/api/hc/' + id, 
                  {title: 'new',
                   shortname: 'new',
                  summary: 'new',
                  description: 'new'}
                  )
           .success(function(data) {

        })
        .error(function(data) {
            console.log('Error: ' + data);
        });
};
```

My express: Nothing seems to be getting passed the the JSON values, for some reason all of the fields and keys are wiped clean, leaving only the _id and _v keys and values.

```
.put(function(req, res) {
    Service.findById(req.params._id, function(err, service) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        service.title = req.body.title;     // update the items info
        service.summary = req.body.summary;
        service.shortname = req.body.shortname;
        service.description = req.body.description;
        // save the items
        service.save(function(err) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
            res.json({ message: 'Service updated!' });
        });
    });
})
```

My view

```
 <form name="editForm" ng-submit="editService(service._id)" ng-repeat="service in services 
 filter:json">
  <input type="text" placeholder="{{ service.title}}" ng-model="serviceTitle" required>
  <input type="text" placeholder="{{ service.shortname}}" ng-model="serviceShortname" required>
  <input type="text" placeholder="{{ service.description}}" ng-model="serviceSummary" required>
  <textarea type="text" placeholder="{{ service.summary}}" ng-model="serviceDescription" required></textarea>
  <button type="submit">Edit</button>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually putting data in the example you gave.

```
$http.put('/api/hc/' + id)
```

should be

```
$http.put('/api/hc/' + id, formData)
```

where `formData` is whatever object you glean from the form fields you want to send up the pipe.  Also, have a gander at angular's `$[resource][1]` service, it's a much cleaner (imo) way to do REST clients than using `$http` directly.

Comment: Would that be as simple as adding: $scope.editService = function(id) {
  $http.put('/api/hc/' + id, formData)
           .success(function(data) {
   
   })
   .error(function(data) {
    console.log('Error: ' + data);
   });
 };

Comment: yep, though I'd recommend some kind of UI update on success as well.  Well, assuming that you have formData already built; that doesn't come in automatically.  It's usually going to be an object on $scope that you bind your form fields to.

Comment: hmmm, for some reason it's having the same effect and deleting both keys and values in the JSON object.

Comment: Your help got me closer to the answer. I currently have the fields being replaced with 'new'. How would I make these pick up on the form field inputs?

Comment: I figured it out here in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25161885/angular-passing-scope-data-into-put-request/25162180#25162180
Your answer helped me out tremendously though. Thank you!